# Jquery checkbox .prop click preventDefault behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, onclick, onchange

I have been working with many checkboxes lately. 
I came across this 'problem' with the `.prevenDefault()` click event and I tried to find a solution for this.
In my case I wanted to be able to decide if a checkbox could be checked/unchecked according to other fields. Sometimes I even had to open a dialog before the event fired.
This sounded easier than it turned out to be...

In [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPUyv/2/) you can see what the problem is and how I tried to solve it (see code below as well). Most answers implied to use change instead of click. But than you can't use `.preventdefault()`.

```
$('div').off('change','.wtf').on('change', '.wtf', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    //return false;
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        alert('I am true now, but I must stay false');
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        alert('I am false now, but I must stay true');
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Is this the best solution? Or is there any other way to make the checkbox wait untill it is allowed to change it's state?

As example: I would like the checkbox unchecked only if a user agrees with a message in a dialog by hitting 'OK'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Checkboxes are a special case where the `change` event and `click` can replace each-other since the `change event` is also fired by clicking on the checkbox.

That said the only big difference between `click` and `change` is the usability of `.preventDefault()`. The change event is better in cases where the value of the checkbox is being changed using any other methods than clicking.

In this case you choose whichever you prefer. An example would be: [*Fiddle here*](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/HPUyv/9/)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    var ch = $(this), c;
    if (ch.is(':checked')) {
        ch.prop('checked', false);
        c = confirm('Do you?');
        if (c) {
            ch.prop('checked', true);
        }
    } else {
        ch.prop('checked', true);
        c = confirm('Are you sure?');
        if (c) {
            ch.prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still I find these checkboxes somewhat illogical if you compare with other form element handling...

Comment: True, they are a little different since they have a value but also  an on/off status (checked or not). And that makes them more tricky.

Comment: Also note, that click and change events fire differently on Firefox and Chrome. Firefox: first click, then change. Chrome: first change, then click.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented [**Spokey**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16213398/1592845) solution with some modifications based on stop the function using `return` if the `confirm()` returns `true`

```
$("input[name='status']").change(function(e){
       if ($(this).is(':checked')){
           msg = "{{__('The set status will be Active again! Are you sure?')}}"
           a = confirm(msg);
           if (a){
               return true;
           }
           $(this).prop('checked',false)
       }
       else{
           msg = "{{__('The set will be Inactive! Are you sure?')}}"
           a = confirm(msg);
            if (a){
               return true;
           }
           $(this).prop('checked',true);
       }
   })
```